# Page with Kendo detailTemplate can not load with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, templates, colors, kendo-ui

On a page (partialView), I have a kendo grid with a detailTemplate.

$('#myGrid').kendoGrid({

```
detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
```

My template is like

```
        <div id="template">
            <table style="background-color:#EE00EE">
                <tr>
```

With IE, the page load correctly, but not with Chrome or FF.
If I take off style="background-color:#EE00EE" , then it is ok.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recognized as kendo template and in kendo template you are accesing js variables with # tag, becouse of that kendo is trying to read variable with name EE00EE that does not exists. You need to escape `#` tag like this: `\\#EE00EE` or use standard colors or use rbg filter.

Example: [escape # tag in template](https://dojo.telerik.com/EmIFAweM)

Comment: Great. Work perfectly.  Thanks.